# UWP - Pedometer exception

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp-xaml

I have in  XAML TextBlock with name StpTextBlock and button with name **btnPedometra**.
[image]

also in code this :
[image]

and it is returning this exception : [image]

Comment: Try to show your code as text in order to others see what it looks like. Copy your exception text below for the same reason and don't forget to mark the place where the exception is thrown and what type of exception it is.

Comment: Add complete stacktrace of your NullReferenceException - in TEXT

Comment: As @rudolf_franek said, please share the code and error in **text** not **pictures**. With just screenshot, it's hard to reproduce and identify your problem. :(

Answer (score 0):

Local variable

```
Pedometer readings
```

remains null after assignment from `await Pedometer.GetdefaultAsync()`

`readings.Interval = 120;` throws Exception because `readings` is null

You need to find out why `Pedometer.GetdefaultAsync()` returns null.

Comment: Can you send me link ?

Comment: for current answer ? Because i can not found it

Comment: It is indeed in the response above - if you feel your problem is broader you have to describe it better.

Answer (score 0):

As @rudolf_franek's answer said, you got the `NullReferenceException` because 
the `readings` returned by [Pedometer.GetdefaultAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.sensors.pedometer#Windows_Devices_Sensors_Pedometer_GetDefaultAsync) is `null`.

[Pedometer.GetdefaultAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.sensors.pedometer#Windows_Devices_Sensors_Pedometer_GetDefaultAsync) returns a [Pedometer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.sensors.pedometer) object that represents the default sensor. If there is no pedometer sensor, the return value will be null. So while using [Pedometer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.sensors.pedometer), please make sure your device has pedometer sensor. And in the code, check this by determining if the return value of [Pedometer.GetdefaultAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.sensors.pedometer#Windows_Devices_Sensors_Pedometer_GetDefaultAsync) is `null`.

```
var readings= await Pedometer.GetDefaultAsync();
if (null == readings)
{
    MessageDialog showDialog = new MessageDialog("No pedometer available");
    await showDialog.ShowAsync();
}
else
{
    readings.ReportInterval = readings.MinimumReportInterval;
    readings.ReadingChanged += Readings_ReadingChanged;
}
```

For more info, please refer to the official [**Pedometer sample**](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Pedometer) on GitHub.